# Creating Excel workbook gives error no server

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create excel file and it works on the development machine, but not on server. The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 and the installed Office version is 2010 x86.

I can open excel file on the server, but if I want generate Excel file I have an error.
"Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space."

The code I am using is:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();  // Error at this line.
```

I guess the problem is with configuration, but I cannot find where.
Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Check folder permission.

Comment: Check the path where the files are created.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET app? WCF? Service?

Comment: This is MVC application. At point of error I do not set directory yet.

Comment: Excel does not keep files in memory, so adding a workbook requires access to the file system.  Does your App Pool user have a 'Temp' directory set that has read/write access?

Comment: Hi Steve, I am not familiar with App Pool user. Can you tell me how and where i should check it and if possible to change it.